How do I initialize a signal in Simulink once the required condition is met?
My system is as shown where I read an input from a displacement sensor. If the input is more than absolute 0.5, I want the system to output the signal present in the signal builder. I am currently trying to use an enabled subsystem to ensure that the voltage output only happens if the condition becomes true. However, the output signal does not start from T=0, it starts from whatever time has elapsed since the start of the simulation (e.g., if the condition was first met at T = 10 s, it outputs the signal from its intermediate value at T = 10 s]. How should I set the system up such that the output signal starts from its initial point when the condition becomes true?
Notes:
In the enable subsystem, "States when enabling" is set to reset.
My sample time for the Signal Builder is 0.
I cannot set the sample time for the enable subsystem (its set to -1 by default), as the Enable block is not at the root.
Image of current Simulink setup:

Things tried so far:

I've tried using enabled, triggered and reset subsystems.
I've tried letting the input signal be within the enable subsystem with the sample time set to 0.
I've tried to use a reset subsystem nested with an enable system, as well nested enable subsystems.
I've tried using "From workspace" source instead of signal builder.


This likely isn't possible with the signal builder block, could you define what signal you're trying to generate so we might suggest alternative ways of doing so?

It's a pulse signal with varying pulse interval (depending on how the physical system is reacting) e.g., if the first interval is 0.1 s, the second one could be 0.07 s with the third one as 0.06 s.
